# When I change screen orientation using sensor ImageView becomes blank in android?

Tags: android, imageview, orientation

Here i am using following code

Here the problem is to using following code i am picked image from gallery and set in ImageView but when i rotate screen the ImageView become blank. So give me the solution for how to save state and displaying the image.

```
 FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // Create intent to Open Image applications like Gallery, Google Photos
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                    android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            // Start the Intent
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMG);
            //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
            //.setAction("Action", null).show();
            //Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this,firstActivity.class);
            //startActivity(i);
        }
    });


}

@Override
protected  void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    try {
        // When an Image is picked
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMG && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && null != data) {
            // Get the Image from data

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            // Get the cursor
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
                    filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            // Move to first row
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            imgDecodableString = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            // Set the Image in ImageView after decoding the String
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory
                    .decodeFile(imgDecodableString));

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You haven't picked Image",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Time rotation restart the activity. This restart must be prevented.

Add the following code in the manifest file in the desired activity

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: This code can work but there is one problem its not work for landscape image

Comment: If you want the screen in horizontal position was manifest file you want to add the following code to the activity which do

' android:screenOrientation="landscape" '

Answer (score 0):

use this in manifest activity tag.
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"

Answer (score 0):

When you change orientation, if you doesn't add

```
 android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

in manifest -> activity will re-create. Please re-check it.